# How can I add a hospital to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

A manager of a hospital in my city wanted to add his hospital to Google Maps with mark "H". How can we add it? I searched but just found "How to add a Local Business:. But I want also marked with "H".

like this:

[image: example of how I want this to look.]

How can I do this?

Comment: I would recommend asking on google forums rather than here, it is possible they keep those "points of interest" in their database and you should ask them to add your location

Comment: I asked today and waiting response now, I hope they will help me Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

You should contact Google directly to do this. Your best bet would be to use one of the options on this [Google Maps Support page.](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=98014)

> ### Fix an error on Google Maps
>
> **Help us make Maps better**
>
> Community edits allow you to modify the information you see on Google
>   Maps, making it more accurate for everyone.
>
> Find out how you can:
>
> - Report incorrect map data
> - Add a point of interest
> - Move the marker from an inaccurate location
> - Edit inaccurate details for a local business
> - Report a listing on Google Maps
> - Track your edits